# Github won't upload some folders of project

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, github, repository

I'm trying to use the Github app for Mac to upload a repo, but it won't let me upload some folders. It automatically unchecks their boxes, and pressing 'select all' selects every box other tham then, too. If I tick them again, it will upload everything other than them, and they'll appear on Github only as folder icons, not actually as folders.

One of the folders is my app's example project. The other is some code from another repo.

How can I get it to upload these files?

Comment: the github app is for really basic stuff i thing. i would recommend you to use the terminal for the most stress free workflow. i tried the app and also the xcode own function to handle repositories but at the end I'm still in the terminal.

Comment: @Andrew Did you try my answer?? Any improvement?

Answer (score 0):

You need to stage those files first to `commit`. If not, then those files are not committed and you cannot upload them to `github`. **To stage your files, open your terminal, go to the path of your project and add the unstaged files to commit.**

Like this:

```
git add .
git add -u
```

the above commands are used to add and stage the unstaged files.

```
git commit -m "message"
```

to commit the staged files. (After you staged the changes, you can commit also with github for mac software too).

Comment: i like to use `git commit -am "message"`

Comment: @KalliDalli That's cool. I haven't know that thing. You made me learn this. Thank you. http://schacon.github.io/git/git-commit.html